# UIPopoverController + UINavigationController = Delegate problems

Tags: ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have two views setup ( inside a TabBar). The DetailView with a button that calls a PopOver with a NavigationController+UITableView (RootView) loading data from CoreData. I have a problem passing data from the UITableView to the DetailView. I have a protocol declared in RootView and used in the DetailView.

Here is the code I use to create the PopOver from the button because I think I have some delegate issues. Any help will be amazing,

```
- (IBAction)zoneListButtonController
{
    if (self.controladorPopOver == nil) {

        ipadrootviewController = [[iPadRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPadRootView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UINavigationController *ipadnavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                 initWithRootViewController:ipadrootviewController];

        UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ipadnavController];

        self.controladorPopOver = popover;
        popover.delegate = self;
        self.title = @"Countries";
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 300);
        [self.controladorPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(112, 20, 86, 27) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];


        [ipadnavController release];
        [controladorPopOver release];
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a protocol declared in RootView (ipadrootviewController) but where are you setting DetailView as the delegate?  Does RootView have a delegate property for the protocol?  What do you mean exactly by the protocol is "used in the DetailView"?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
SubZone1 *theSubZone1 = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSNumber *condition;
condition = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    if ([condition isEqualToNumber:theSubZone1.sz]) {
        [delegate SubZone1Tap:theSubZone1.name];
        NSLog(theSubZone1.name);
} else {
       ....I push the third level controller
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

An instance of the `SubZone1iPadController` doesn't exist when you create the popover in `DetailView` so you can't set its delegate property directly from the `DetailView`.

One option is to also add the delegate property to the `iPadRootViewController` which you can set in the `zoneListButtonController` method.  Then, when `ipadrootviewController` creates the `SubZone1iPadController`, pass along the delegate.

So in both `ipadrootviewController` and `SubZone1iPadController`, add a `delegate` property:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) id <SubZone1Tap> delegate;
```

Then, in the `zoneListButtonController` method, set the delegate property on `iPadRootViewController`:

```
ipadrootviewController = [[iPadRootViewController alloc] init...
ipadrootviewController.delegate = self;
```

Then, where `ipadrootviewController` creates `SubZone1iPadController`:

```
SubZone1iPadController *sz1 = [[SubZone1iPadController alloc] init...
sz1.delegate = self.delegate;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:...
[sz1 release];
```

Finally, in the `DetailView`, make sure the delegate method is implemented.  For example:

```
-(void)SubZone1Tap:(NSString *)name
{
    NSLog(@"SubZone1Tap, name = %@", name);

    //dismiss the popover if that's what you need to do...
    [controladorPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```